# Solving Security Vulnerability https://symfony.com/cve-2020-15094

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, symfony4

In order to solve the vulnerability described above, I have updated this old PHP project from Symfony 4.1.*.

I update to Symfony 4.4.13 using the steps describe in this excellent [blog](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony5-upgrade/upgrade-4.4)

Unfortunately, I starting getting NGINX 502 errors on most of my endpoints.

Do you know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending more than 2 days messing around with dependencies using composer, I have came across this other excellent [blog](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/nginx-502-bad-gateway-errors-php-fpm/) for troubleshooting NGINX errors.

Looking into the error log located at `/var/log/nginx/error.log`, I have noticed that the endpoints were failing with this error:
nginx upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream

The solution was to increase the fastcgi buffer size

```
server {
    listen 8080 default_server;

    server_name _;
    root /var/www/public;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;

        # Required since we have update to symfony 4.4.13 (because of security vulnerability in http-kernel), we need to
        # increase the size buffer for the response from FPM
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    }
}
```

and then to reload the nginx

`/etc/init.d/nginx reload`